# Overwrite entries in an existing csv file using Pandas in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

I want to read a few rows from a csv file using Pandas and convert the read data into Numpy arrays, do some arithmetic operations on these arrays and then overwrite the existing rows in the csv file with these arrays. I have the following code to do this but I am not sure how to specify the exact write location when using Pandas.

The sample csv file looks as follows:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

X = Nodes[0:Nnodes,0]
Y = Nodes[0:Nnodes,1]
Z = Nodes[0:Nnodes,2]

X = X.reshape(Nnodes,1)
Y = Y.reshape(Nnodes,1)
Z = Z.reshape(Nnodes,1)

# Do some mathematical operation on the selected arrays 

X = X*0.5
Y = Y*0.5
Y = X*0.5


# Concatenate the three arrays

Data = np.concatenate((X, Y, Z),axis = 1)

# Convert the array back into a dataframe

df  =pd.DataFrame(Data)

# Overwrite the previously selected arrays at the same location in the csv file 

df.to_csv("test.csv",header = None,index = False, sep = '\t', mode = 'w')
```

I am not sure if Pandas is the most appropriate tool for this. Any help/suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `The sample csv file looks as follows:` - I don't see commas (Comma Separated Values) but the good new is it looks like the lines all use the same width.  It that is true throughout the file then the position of the nth line is (n-1) * (width including any \r \n characters at the end of the line).  Normally CSV files have variable length lines and you need to re-write the file to make changes.

Comment: @DaveS. Unfortunately the all lines do not have the same width. Is there any other way I can modify the existing file in python ?

Comment: Not really.  File overwrites can't push the data after the changed lines away to make room if the new lines are longer, or  close up a gap if the new lines are shorter.  For variable-length lines you need to open file 1 to read, open file 2 to write, copy lines 1-(n-1), write the new lines n to m, read and discard n to m in file 1, copy lines m+1 to z.   Or if the file isn't too big read all lines into memory, change lines, write all lines back to a file.